# large chunk of project needing help on. new to java programming

Tags: java, passwords, authenticator

okay so this is long. I am working on a project for class and we were given examples on what to do. i am very new to this so i did what i thought i could but i just cannot seem to get this right and probably have tons of errors and incorrect things in this code. this is for a password authentication system and is only half of it. i commented out the generate password function because i have not gotten there yet. the whole program compiles but it always generates that the password is incorrect.

```
    public class FinalLab7
    {
    public static void main( String[] args )
     {

       // if (args.length == 0) // Generate password
        //{

        //System.out.println("Your new password is: " + generateValidPassword());

        //} 
        if (args.length == 1) // Test password
        {          
            System.out.print("The password you entered, " + args[0]);

            if (isValidPassword(args[0]))
            {
                System.out.println(" is a valid password");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(" is NOT a valid password");
            }    
        }
        else // To many command line arguments, educate user
        {

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("This program takes either zero or one parameter.");
            System.out.println("When run with zero parameters it will generate a password.");
            System.out.print("When run with one parameter it will test whether"); 
            System.out.println(" the parameter is a valid password.");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("A valid password has the following four properties:");
            System.out.println("1. A valid password contains between 8 and 14 characters, inclusive.");
            System.out.println("2. A valid password contains two or more uppercase letters [A-Z].");
            System.out.println("3. A valid password contains two or more lowercase letters [a-z]");
            System.out.println("4. A valid password contains two or more numbers [0-9]");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
        }
   } 

static private boolean isValidPassword(String testPassword) 
 { 
     boolean returnValue = false;
     int uppercasecount = 0;
     int lowercasecount = 0;
     int numbercount = 0;


    if(uppercasecount>=2&&lowercasecount>=2&&numbercount>=2)
    {
        returnValue = true;
    }
    return returnValue;
}
    static public boolean CharacterIsNumber(char testChar) 
    { 
        int numbercount = 0;
        boolean returnValue = false;
        switch (testChar)
        {
            case '0':
                returnValue = true;
                //numbercount++;
                break;
            case '1':
                returnValue = true;
                //numbercount++;
                break;
            case '2':
                returnValue = true;
                //numbercount++;
                break;
            case '3':
                returnValue = true;
                //numbercount++;
                break;
            case '4':
                returnValue = true;
                //numbercount++;
                break;
            case '5':
                returnValue = true;
                //numbercount++;
                break;            
            case '6':
                returnValue = true;
                //numbercount++;
                break;
            case '7':
                returnValue = true;
                //numbercount++;
                break;
            case '8':
                returnValue = true;
                //numbercount++;
                break;
            case '9':
                returnValue = true;
                //numbercount++;
                break;           
        }
        numbercount++;
        return returnValue;
    }
    static public boolean CharacterIsUppercase(char testChar) 
    {
        int uppercasecount = 0;
        boolean returnValue = false;

        switch (testChar)
            {
                case 'A':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //uppercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'B':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //uppercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'C':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //uppercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'D':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //uppercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'E':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //uppercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'F':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //uppercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'G':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //uppercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'H':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //uppercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'I':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //uppercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'J':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //uppercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'K':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //uppercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'L':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //uppercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'M':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //uppercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'N':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //uppercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'O':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //uppercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'P':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //uppercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'Q':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //uppercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'R':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //uppercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'S':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //uppercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'T':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //uppercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'U':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //uppercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'V':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //uppercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'W':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //uppercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'X':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //uppercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'Y':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //uppercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'Z':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //uppercasecount++;
                    break;
            }

        uppercasecount++;
        return returnValue;
    }
    static public boolean CharacterIsLowercase(char testChar) 
    {
        int lowercasecount = 0;
        boolean returnValue = false;

        switch (testChar)
            {
                case 'a':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //lowercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'b':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //lowercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'c':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //lowercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'd':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //lowercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'e':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //lowercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'f':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //lowercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'g':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //lowercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'h':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //lowercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'i':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //lowercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'j':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //lowercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'k':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //lowercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'l':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //lowercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'm':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //lowercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'n':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //lowercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'o':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //lowercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'p':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //lowercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'q':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //lowercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'r':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //lowercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 's':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //lowercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 't':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //lowercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'u':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //lowercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'v':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //lowercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'w':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //lowercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'x':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //lowercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'y':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //lowercasecount++;
                    break;
                case 'z':
                    returnValue = true;
                    //lowercasecount++;
                    break;
            }

        lowercasecount++;
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

I commented out a few different parts, such as the uppercasecount++ functions, because i tried different methods that did not work. this section is supposed to check if the password has 2 uppercase, 2 lowercase, and 2 numbers and it will either display "The password you entered is valid or invalid" depending on the case. this only displays invalid every time.

Comment: Could you give us some expected input/output vs what you're getting? Also, just out of curiosity, why don't you use the static methods defined in the [Character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) class such as isDigit and isUpperCase()?

Comment: A hint to reduce those long switch statements: A char is just an unsigned value in an ASCII table. These values also appear one after the other. That is, 'a' appears before 'b' but not necessarily after 'Z'. This means instead of long switch statements, you can test a range.

For example, you can say,

**if (testChar >= 'a' && testChar <= 'z') {
  returnValue = true;
  }
  lowerCaseCount++;
  return lowerCaseCount;**

Also methods from the Character class, such as what @PakkuDon pointed out work just as well.

Comment: I am still new in java and i am going off of what i have learned so far in my class (which i believe this is a little too complex for my knowledge so far). any help or small teaching here would be greatly helpful.

Comment: You can browse the API for methods from the Character class. Also, you can look an ASCII table if you'd rather test the decimal or hex values of a character rather than the character comparisons themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code came from the method *isValidPassword()**. You were checking to see if it matched the conditions, but you never incremented the variables. I have updated your code to shorten it. Also, it removed the error from your code. Compare your code with this code. Also, this code does not work. I only fixed the errors and shortened your code a little.

```
package test;

/**
 *
 * @author Tyler Weaver
 */
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // if (args.length == 0) // Generate password
        //{

        //System.out.println("Your new password is: " + generateValidPassword());
        //} 
        if (args.length == 1) // Test password
        {
            System.out.print("The password you entered, " + args[0]);

            if (isValidPassword(args[0])) {
                System.out.println(" is a valid password");
            } else {
                System.out.println(" is NOT a valid password");
            }
        } else // To many command line arguments, educate user
        {

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("This program takes either zero or one parameter.");
            System.out.println("When run with zero parameters it will generate a password.");
            System.out.print("When run with one parameter it will test whether");
            System.out.println(" the parameter is a valid password.");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("A valid password has the following four properties:");
            System.out.println("1. A valid password contains between 8 and 14 characters, inclusive.");
            System.out.println("2. A valid password contains two or more uppercase letters [A-Z].");
            System.out.println("3. A valid password contains two or more lowercase letters [a-z]");
            System.out.println("4. A valid password contains two or more numbers [0-9]");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    static private boolean isValidPassword(String testPassword) {
        int uppercasecount = 0;
        int lowercasecount = 0;
        int numbercount = 0;

        for (int count = 0; count < testPassword.length(); count++) {
            char cur = testPassword.charAt(count);

            if (CharacterIsNumber(cur)) {
                numbercount++;
            } else if (CharacterIsUppercase(cur)) {
                uppercasecount++;
            } else if (CharacterIsLowercase(cur)) {
                lowercasecount++;
            }
        }

        return (uppercasecount >= 2 && 
                lowercasecount >= 2 &&
                numbercount >= 2);
    }

    static public boolean CharacterIsNumber(char testChar) {
        return Character.isDigit(testChar);
    }

    static public boolean CharacterIsUppercase(char testChar) {
        return Character.isUpperCase(testChar);
    }

    static public boolean CharacterIsLowercase(char testChar) {
        return Character.isLowerCase(testChar);
    }
}
```

As a side note: Unless you're not using an IDE, i'd refrain from using args[] command line. If using an IDE it will not always work properly. I'd suggest the Scanner class if you are new.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! that function works now. now i can work on the other function of the code :D